# How to prevent all symbols from static library to load and why other symbols from same .o file get exported to test while linking static library

Tags: c, linux, linker, static-libraries

Suppose there are three c files, say `a.c` contains functions  `xx()`, `yy()` and `b.c` contains `nn()`, `mm()` and `c.c` contains `qq()`, `rr()`.

I made a static library `stat.a` out of `a.o`, `b.o` and `c.o`. If I link `stat.a` into a test which calls `xx()`, then symbol `yy()` also gets exported: `nm test` has both symbols `xx` and `yy`.

1. I would like to know why the symbols `qq` and `rr` do not get exported ?
2. Is there any method to prevent any other symbols than `xx` being loaded?

Comment: Strip the symbols from the final executable?

Comment: would it be possible to show some code (mcve)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation of your scenario:

**a.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void xx(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}

void yy(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**b.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nn(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}

void mm(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**c.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void qq(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}

void rr(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**test.c**

```
extern void xx(void);

int main(void)
{
    xx();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile all the `*.c` files to `*.o` files:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c a.c b.c c.c test.c
```

Make a static library `stat.a`, containing `a.o`, `b.o`, `c.o`:

```
$ ar rcs stat.a a.o b.o c.o
```

Link program `test`, inputting `test.o` and `stat.a`:

```
$ gcc -o test test.o stat.a
```

Run:

```
$ ./test
xx
```

Let's see the symbol tables of the object files in `stat.a`:

```
$ nm stat.a

a.o:
0000000000000000 r __func__.2250
0000000000000003 r __func__.2254
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
0000000000000000 T xx
0000000000000013 T yy

b.o:
0000000000000000 r __func__.2250
0000000000000003 r __func__.2254
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000013 T mm
0000000000000000 T nn
                 U puts

c.o:
0000000000000000 r __func__.2250
0000000000000003 r __func__.2254
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
0000000000000000 T qq
0000000000000013 T rr
```

The definitions (`T`) of `xx`, `yy` are in member `stat.a(a.o)`. Definitions of `nn`, `mm`
are in `stat.a(b.o)`. Definitions of `qq`, `rr` are in `stat.a(c.o)`.

Let's see which of those symbols are also defined in the symbol table of the program `test`:

```
$ nm test | egrep 'T (xx|yy|qq|rr|nn|mm)'
000000000000064a T xx
000000000000065d T yy
```

`xx`, which is *called* in the program, is defined. `yy`, which is *not* called, is also
defined. `nn`, `mm`, `qq` and `rr`, none of which are called, are all absent.

That's what you've observed.

> I would like to know why the symbols `qq` and `rr` do not get exported?

What is a *static library*, such as `stat.a`, and what is its special role in a linkage?

It is an [`ar` archive](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) that conventionally - but not necessarily - contains nothing
but object files. You can offer such an archive to the linker from which to select the
object files it *needs*, if any, to carry on the linkage. The linker *needs* those object
files in the archive that provide definitions for symbols that have been
referenced, but not yet defined, in input files it has already linked. The
linker extracts the *needed* object files from the archive and inputs them to the
linkage, exactly as if they were individually named input files and the static library
was not mentioned at all.

So what the linker does with an input static library is different from what it does
with an input *object file*. Any input object file is linked into the output file *unconditionally*
(whether it is needed or not).

In this light, let's redo the linkage of `test` with some diagnostics (`-trace)` to show what
files are actually linked:

```
$ gcc -o test test.o stat.a -Wl,--trace
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
test.o
(stat.a)a.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Apart from all the boiler-plate files for a C program linkage that `gcc` adds by
default, the only files of *ours* in the linkage are the two object files:

```
test.o
(stat.a)a.o
```

The linkage:

```
$ gcc -o test test.o stat.a
```

is *exactly the same* as the linkage:

```
$ gcc -o test test.o a.o
```

Let's think that through.

- `test.o` was the first linker input. This object file was linked unconditionally into the program.
- `test.o` contains a reference (specifically, a function call) to `xx` but no definition of the function `xx`.
- So the linker now needs to find a definition of `xx` to complete the linkage.
- The next linker input is the static library `stat.a`.
- The linker searches `stat.a` for an object file that contains a defintion of `xx`.
- It finds `a.o`. It extracts `a.o` from the archive and links it into the program.
- There are no other unresolved symbol references in the linkage for which the
  linker can find definitions in `stat.a(b.o)` or `stat(c.o)`. So neither of those
  object files is extracted and linked.

By extracting an linking (just) `stat.a(a.o)` the linker has got a definition
of `xx` that it needed to resolved the function call in `test.o`. But `a.o` *also* contains
the definition of `yy`. So that definition is also linked into the program.
`nn`, `mm`, `qq` and `rr` are not defined in the program because none of them
are defined in the object files that were linked into the program.

That's the answer to your first question. Your second is:

> Is there any method to prevent any other symbols than `xx` being loaded?

There are at least two ways.

One is simply to define each of `xx`, `yy`, `nn`, `mm`, `qq`, `rr` *in a source
file by itself*. Then compile object files `xx.o`, `yy.o`, `nn.o`, `mm.o`, `qq.o`, `rr.o`
and archive all of them in `stat.a`. Then, if the linker ever needs to find an
object file in `stat.a` that defines `xx`, it will find `xx.o`, extract and link it,
and the definition of `xx` *alone* will be added to linkage.

There's another way that does not require you code just one function in each source
file. This way depends on the fact that an ELF object file, as produced by the
compiler, is composed of various *sections* and these sections are in fact the
units that the linker distinguishes and merges together into the output file. By
default, there is a standard ELF section for each kind of symbol. The
compiler places all of the function definitions in one *code* section and
all data definitions in an appropriate *data* section. The reason that your
linkage of program `test` contains the definitions of both `xx` and `yy` is that
the compiler has placed both of these definitions in the single code section of `a.o`,
so the linker can either merge that code section into the program, or not: it can
only link the definitions of `xx` *and* `yy`, or neither of them, so it is obliged
to link both, even though only `xx` is needed. Let's see the disassembly of the code section of `a.o`. By default the
code section is is called `.text`:

```
$ objdump -d a.o

a.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <xx>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # b <xx+0xb>
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <xx+0x10>
  10:   90                      nop
  11:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  12:   c3                      retq

0000000000000013 <yy>:
  13:   55                      push   %rbp
  14:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  17:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 1e <yy+0xb>
  1e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  23 <yy+0x10>
  23:   90                      nop
  24:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  25:   c3                      retq
```

There you see the definitions of `xx` and `yy`, both in the `.text` section.

But you can *ask* the compiler to place the definition of each global symbol
*in its own section* in the object file. Then the linker can seperate the code
section for any function definition from any other, and you can ask the linker
to throw away any sections that aren't used in the output file. Let's try that.

Compile all the source files again, this time asking for a separate section per symbol:

```
$ gcc -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -c a.c b.c c.c test.c
```

Now look again at the disassembly of `a.o`:

```
$ objdump -d a.o

a.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text.xx:

0000000000000000 <xx>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # b <xx+0xb>
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <xx+0x10>
  10:   90                      nop
  11:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  12:   c3                      retq

Disassembly of section .text.yy:

0000000000000000 <yy>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # b <yy+0xb>
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <yy+0x10>
  10:   90                      nop
  11:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  12:   c3                      retq
```

Now we've got *two* code sections in `a.o`: `.text.xx`, containing only the definition of `xx`,
and `.text.yy`, containing only the definition of `yy`. The linker can merge either of
these sections into a program and not merge the other.

Rebuild `stat.a`

```
$ rm stat.a
$ ar rcs stat.a a.o b.o c.o
```

Relink the program, this time asking the linker to discard unused input sections
(`-gc-sections`). We'll also ask it to trace the files it loads (`-trace`)
and to print a mapfile for us (`-Map=mapfile`):

```
$ gcc -o test test.o stat.a -Wl,-gc-sections,-trace,-Map=mapfile
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
test.o
(stat.a)a.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

The `-trace` output is exactly the same as before. But check again which of our
symbols are defined in the program:

```
$ nm test | egrep 'T (xx|yy|qq|rr|nn|mm)'
000000000000064a T xx
```

Only `xx`, which is what you want.

The output of the program is the same as before:

```
$ ./test
xx
```

Finally look at the mapfile. Near the top you see:

**mapfile**

```
...
Discarded input sections
...
...
 .text.yy       0x0000000000000000       0x13 stat.a(a.o)
...
...
```

The linker was able to throw away the redundant code section `.text.yy` from
the input file `stat.a(a.o)`. That's why the redundant definition of `yy` is
no longer in the program.

Comment: @coddygeek Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

1. I would like to know why the symbols qq and rr do not get exported ?

You have to inform the linker of your intention [How to force gcc to link an unused static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library)

> gcc -L./ -o test test.c -Wl,--whole-archive stat.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive

2. Is there any method to prevent any other symbols than xx being loaded?

From [How do I include only used symbols when statically linking with gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307348/how-do-i-include-only-used-symbols-when-statically-linking-with-gcc)

> gcc -ffunction-sections -c a.c
>
> gcc -L./ -o test test.c -Wl,--gc-sections stat.a

Comment: This -ffunction not found working.suppose a.c contain xx() and yy(),and a.o is made using flag ffunction-sections and stat.a made out of a.o,then it links to a test.c which give a binary test on compilation .On verification with nm test shows both symbols xx and yy.@rantan pan